# Laravel ajax 500 (Internal Server Error) error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm getting 500 (Internal Server Error) error working with ajax in laravel 5.6
Here is my code and pages

create.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group row">
            <label for="filiere" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Filiere</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="nom" id="filiere" class="custom-select">
                    @foreach($filieres as $filiere)
                        <option value="{{$filiere->id}}">{{$filiere->nom}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="matiere" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Matiere</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="nom" id="matiere" class="custom-select">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){ /* DOM ready */
        $("#filiere").change(function() {

            var id_filiere = $(this).val();
            var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "{!! route('select-ajax-2') !!}",
                method: 'POST',
                data: {id_filiere: id_filiere, _token: token},
                success:function(data) {
                    $("#matiere").html('');
                    $("#matiere").html(data.options);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:enseignant'], function() {
Route::post('select-ajax-2', 'CourController@selectAjax')->name('select-ajax-2');
});
```

CourController.php

```
public function selectAjax(Request $request) {
    if($request->ajax()) {

        $matieres = DB::table('filiere_matiere')
        ->join('matieres', 'matiere_id', '=', 'matieres.id')
        ->select('matiere.nom', 'matiere.id', 'filiere_id')
        ->where('filiere_id', '=', $request->id_filiere)
        ->get();


        $matieres = view('cours.ajax-select', compact('matieres')->render());
        return response()->json(['options' => $matiere]);
    }
}
```

ajax-select.blade.php

```
@if (!empty($matieres))
@foreach ($matieres as $matiere)
    <option value="{{$matiere->id}}">{{$matiere->nom}}</option>
@endforeach
@endif
```

I think everything is set up correctly but it's still showing me this error

POST http://localhost/school/public/select-ajax-2 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Check the logs on your server. It's an issue with the PHP, most likely data access given the logic.

Comment: Use; `ini_set("display_errors", "on"); error_reporting(E_ALL);` (in a separate file included at the start) and paste the error that you get

Comment: Check your logfile i.e /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: Call to a member function render() on array {"userId":40,"email":"sayah@prof.com","exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function render() on array at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\school\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\CourController.php:54)
[stacktrace]

Comment: It's fixed! I love you guys